# how to mock http headers and body using junit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am working on a spring api gateway. There is a class `LoggingMethods` which i want to test.
It contains two methods  `appendBodyRequest` and `logRequestNoBody`.

```
Public class LoggingMethods{

  LoggingMethods(ServerHttpRequest request){
  }
  void appendBodyrequest(ByteBuffer byteBuffer , ServerHttpRequest request){
   Log.info("Headers:[{}] , Body:[{}]" , request.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap(),
   StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(byteBuffer)); 
  }
   
  void logRequestNoBody(ServerHttpRequest request){
  Log.info("{} response has no body.",request.getMethod());
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to implement unit testing with JUnit with mock headers and body.
Appreciate your help and suggestions!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach is to implement ServerHttpRequest in your test method by yourself. It may look like this:

```
@Test
void testLogRequestNoBody() {
   ServerHttpRequest request = new ServerHttpRequest() {
      
        @Override
        public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
            return null;
        }

        ...
       
        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.add("test", "test");
            return httpHeaders;
        }
    };

   LoggingMethods loggingMethods = new LoggingMethods(request);
   loggingMethods.logRequestNoBody(request);
}
```

You can specify the headers you need to test inside implemented method. You can implement remained ServerHttpRequest methods by returning `null`.

You don't need Mockito at all in this case. Using Mockito won't give any profit for that purpose.